# Thread.start() does not dispatch from the parent Thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

Basically my code looks like this:

```
private void runFreeThreads() {
    ArrayList<ClassExtendsThread> tmpThreads = new ArrayList<ClassExtendsThread>(freeThreads);
    freeThreads.clear();
    System.out.println("Before the loop");
    for (ClassExtendsThread thread : tmpThreads) {
        thread.start();
    }
    System.out.println("After the loop");
}
```

The problem is I initialise these threads with `this` and `this` has a method called `threadReport()` that looks like

```
public void threadReport(boolean check, ClassExtendsThread someThread) {
        freeThreads.add(someThread);
        if (!check) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Trying to acquire semaphore");
        try {
            reportSem.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        runFreeThreads();
        }
        System.out.println("Semaphore is released!");
        reportSem.release();
    }
```

I use semaphore here like a mutex, where it is essentially initialised with 1. Anyway, I thought `Thread.start()` would actually call the `run()` and then dispatch itself from the parent Thread but it is not.

The run method is:

```
    public class ClassExtendsThread extends Thread {
        private ThreadController tControl;
        private int threadNo;

        public ClassExtendsThread (int threadNo, ThreadController threadController) {
            tControl = threadController;
            this.threadNo = threadNo;
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread no: " + this.threadNo + " is running");
            tControl.tReport(true, this);
        }
  }
```

So I am expecting a result like this (where I also print something at `run()` method):

```
Trying to acquire semaphore
Before the loop
Thread no: 1 is running
Thread no: 2 is running
After the loop
Semaphore is released!
...
```

However in reality what happens is:

```
Trying to acquire semaphore
Before the loop
Thread no: 1 is running
Thread no: 2 is running
Trying to acquire semaphore
Trying to acquire semaphore
```

and then it hangs. Because it never exits the loop. Is there a quick way to fix this?

Comment: Code for run method is also required.

Comment: I would worry more about what is the actual use case you're trying to solve. Your code looks convoluted and highly bug prone. What are you trying to achieve with these threads?

Comment: @Kayaman, it's basically I would like to have threads that are working on a piece of task. Once their task is done, then `run()` calls a method `threadReport()`, which keeps the track of threads that are not working and assigning them tasks.

Comment: Consider to use a ThreadPool. Have a look at the java.util.concurrent package for utility classes: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

Comment: Yes, like Puce said, you're trying to implement something that has already been created, mainly the `Executor` framework. Don't write your own, use a tried and tested version instead.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj I added it now.

Comment: @Puce which one should I use?

Comment: Have a look at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor. It does what you need.